# Обновление DataSource в VS2017

Tags: c#, ms-access

Подключил .accdb к visual studio 2017, потом добавил новое поле в БД через Access, VS не видит нового поля

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нажмите правой кнопкой мыши на подключении к БД и выберите "Обновить". Если не помогает, в более тяжелых случаях, то "Отключить" - "Подключить", и наконец закрыть - открыть Visual Studio